# Copying Android Project to new PC causes ID Errors

Tags: android, import, project

I have a project successfully running on one PC.  I decided to copy this project to another PC and import using 'Existing Android Code into Workspace'.  But immediately on importing the project, I see a host of errors like this

> Public symbol id/radioTest01 declared here is not defined.
>
> Public entry identifier 0x7f0600fb entry index is larger than available symbols (index 251, total symbols 223)

and I can't find R.java in the project...  Googling didn't help much, so I thought I'd post here for any ideas. I would appreciate any feedback.  Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using Gradle and Android Studio regardless of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create a new project and add there the code and files from the other project.

it will add the entries in R.java